# How do I get off of The Lost Isles and go to Azshara

Tags: world-of-warcraft

It's my first time leveling on The Lost Isles and a guide I'm following suggests to go to Azshara next. How do I get off of the Lost Isles and get to Azshara?

Comment: If you follow the quest chain all the way through you should leave as it finishes up.

Comment: so there's no way to leave the quest chain early and move on?

Comment: Not that I know of. I have only leveled up two characters through there though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can naturally leave the lost isles at around level 12 when the quest chain completes. This shouldn't be very long. Goblins, like Worgen and the class Death Knight are locked in a story (phased) zone for much of their early levels.

If you want to meet up with friends early, you need to play a different race to start.

It is possible after a certain point in the story to be summoned out of your zone with the help of a meeting stone or warlock if you level too quickly, however you will forfeit any remaining quests in the area as you can not return. I wouldn't recommend this action as the quests here are more exciting than the rest of the world - they are even voice acted!

Comment: In addition to being more exciting, these quests use a lot of new/fun (to some people) quest mechanics. The entire quest zone should be able to be completed in about 2 hours (If you are reading the quests), less if you are just clicking through the lore.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get off the Lost Isles is to complete the quest line. Any attempt to leave either through summoning, join battle ground or joining a dungeon will result in a message saying you need to complete the Goblin starting quest line. Once finishing the goblin quest line you will find your self at Orgrimmar and can go where ever you want as normal.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a way by accident. I was just questing i was about a level 6 goblin. And my laptop over heated so i had to exit the game completely, then restart to game and when i restarted the game i used my hearthstone to take me back to the questing area, but it instead took me to orgrimmar. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I tested this, it appears that you can get out of *Worgen Zone* but not from *Kezan*

Answer (score 0):

When you beat down the Trade Prince the Orc Thrall gives you a package to take to Ogrimmar.  The quest says to talk to Sassy Hardwrench when you are ready to leave.

Answer (score 0):

When you beat down the Trade Prince the Orc Thrall gives you a package to take to Ogrimmar. The quest says to talk to Sassy Hardwrench when you are ready to leave.

Sassy is on the ship! find him on deck.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, you have to do the quests, and you can't even do something like join a battleground until you have.

Answer (score -1):

You can get off the isle by getting your flight path at either the horde camp or the alliance camp on the coast where the big turtles are.  I've flown back and forth a few times now to keep doing the quests.

Comment: I think you're referring to the Timeless Isle. The question is about The Lost Isles, the goblin starting area.